# How can I run a batch file when Firefox starts?

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-registry, batch-file

I want to run a `.bat` file when any `.exe` file (such as Firefox) is double clicked. I want to run this `.bat` file when Firefox runs. Is there any way to do this?

I tried with this batch code:

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\firefox.exe" /v Debugger /d "D:\Desktop\m.bat" /f
```

Here, `m.bat` is the file which I want to run when Firefox runs.

Image of my Registry:
[image: image of my registry]

Comment: Relevant: [I want to intercept a given program before it runs and run my own program first](//superuser.com/q/1201773)

Comment: ok but how do that

Comment: The answer in the link tells you ...

Comment: ok I understand the solution and appaly  it but there is no any thing happen

Comment: You didn't run the `reg add` command correctly.  In the screen shot of your registry where it shows **m.bat** it should say `firefox.exe`. Also, the data of your **Debugger** value should be `D:\Desktop\m.bat`, not the dash you currently have.  Look more closely at the proposed duplicate answer.

Comment: thank you very much but the code is running m.bat instead of firefox  I don't want that I want firefox run and m.bat running in background

Answer (score 1):

You could use a batch file as wrapper that executes your instruction first and than runs Firefox or the reverse.

In this case you would let the shortcut to Firefox point to the batch.

Comment: yes I want when user running firefox the batch file running in background but how to that